# Connecting instances between 2 VPCs (one public one private) and through a VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS I have two VPCs:

- A public `VPC-A` (connected to Internet using a gateway)
- A private `VPC-B`

The public `VPA-A` has a subnet `VPC-A-Subnet-1` and instance `Instance-A`.

The private `VPC-B` has a subnet `VPC-B-Subnet-1` which has one instance `Instance-B`.

`VPC-B` has also a VPC Endpoint `VPC-B-Endpoint`.

The two VPCs are connected using VPC Peering.

```
                                                Elastic public IP
                                                       |  
VPC-A(Public)---------------- VPC-A-Subnet-1 --- Instance-A (10.0.1.10)
 |(peering) 
 |
VPC-B ----------------------- VPC-B-Subnet-1 --- Instance-B (10.0.0.5)
 |
 |--- VPC-B-Endpoint
```

I want to connect `Instance-A` to `Instance-B` (so `Instance-B` can get data from through `Instance-A` and limit to ssh).

Also I want to connect to `Instance-B` using `VPC-B-Endpoint`.

In the Security Group attached to `Instance-B` I allowed all traffic from `Instance-A` private IP (10.0.1.10).

```
ALL TRAFFIC ............................................ 10.0.1.10
```

With Network Analyzer it appears `Instance-B` can be accessed from `Instance-A`, but if I try to open `Instance-B` IP `10.0.0.5` in a browser in `Instance-A`, the connection is refused.

I can't connect to `Instance-B` from `VPC-B-Endpoint`.

```
         Network Analyzer
Instance-A --------------------> Instance-B (ok reachable)
       |
       |-----------------------> Instance-B (fails)
             Browser


VPC-B-Endpoint -----------> Instance-B (fails)
```

Comment: If peering, security group and NACL are correct, the issue is inside the instance.

Comment: Connection refused in the browser just means that it is refusing to serve a web page. The connectivity seems to be fine. Also, you don't need the VPC Endpoint for this.